# Opposite of "implicate"

Tags: antonyms

What might be a good antonym of *implicate* in the context of troubleshooting an engineering problem?  I can think of *exonerate* and *vindicate* but both sound more about crime than to refer to a component previously thought to introduce a design flaw in the overall system.

Comment: You are already giving two acceptable antonyms; I suggest starting there and using a thesaurus.

Comment: I wound up using _vindicate_ last night since I noticed it used for theorems.

Answer (score 5):

*Rule out, clear,* and *eliminate* are terms commonly so used. Also *checked*.

Related phrases are *no help* and *no joy*.  For example, in a tech's logbook one is more likely to read things like "Swapped EC board, no help.  Swapped TF board, still no joy" than like "Swapped EC board and ruled it out.  Swapped TF board and ruled it out".  I suppose  *no help* to be a severe ellipsis of *It provided no help*.

Comment: Thanks; your first three suggestions tend to require more words of explanation. As for idioms like _no joy_ I try to avoid in likely international settings.  Eg. use of idioms in Polish technical discussions throw me off all the time, and they don't even realize it (in turn, they wouldn't initially get what I mean by "throw off").

Answer (score 2):

In an electronic troubleshooting context:

This blown internal fuse **implicates** an overcurrent of some kind, but **excludes** a short in the devices' power cable being the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The word you might be looking for is `discard/discarded`. It's used a lot when troubleshooting. You usually discard alternatives until you isolate the source of the problem.